# I cant deploy contract on geth

Tags: go-ethereum, metamask

I am trying to deploy my contract using geth on my private network. When i use truffle mirate --reset  shows that is has been deployed but the metamask gives me an error( ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code metamask). So i am using this command
**eth.getTransactionReceipt** with the transaction hash to see if it's ok but the **transactionIndex = 0**. I read that if  transactionIndex
= 0 the contract is not deployed. Right? Can you help? I tried to deployed in remix with the provider of my netowrk and it gives me this error (gas required exceeds allowance (8000000) or always failing transaction)

Below i have the contract code.

```
    pragma solidity ^0.5.8;



contract Creation  {



    struct hero  {
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
        int winCount;
        int trophies;
        int lossCount;
    }
    hero[] public heroes; 


    struct enemy {  
        string name;
        int life;
        int lvl;
        int xp;
        int attack;
    }

    int basiclife=50;

    enemy[] public enemies;

  mapping (uint => address) public herotoowner;
  mapping (address => uint) public  heroCount;

  mapping (uint => address) public monstertoowner;
  uint public monsterCount; 

    function createhero(string memory _name) payable public  { 
     require(heroCount[msg.sender] == 0);
       uint id= heroes.push(hero(_name,basiclife,1,0,20,0,0,0))-1; 
       herotoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       heroCount[msg.sender]++;

    }
     function enemyRage(int _herolvl) public  { 
       uint id=enemies.push(enemy("Rage",20*_herolvl,_herolvl,7*_herolvl,5*_herolvl))-1;
       monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       monsterCount++;

    }

    function enemyDerpina(int _herolvl) public  { 
       uint id=enemies.push(enemy("Derpina",40*_herolvl,_herolvl,14*_herolvl,10*_herolvl))-1; 
       monstertoowner[id] = msg.sender;
       monsterCount++;

    }

       function getHerosByOwner(address owner) external view returns( uint ) { 
        uint result =3;
        for (uint i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              if (herotoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
          }
        }
        return result;
        }
        function getmonstersByOwner(address owner) external view returns( uint ) { 
        uint result =0;
        for (uint i = enemies.length ; i > 0 ; i--) {
              if (monstertoowner[i] == owner) {
                result = i;
                break;
          }
        }
        return result;
        }

        uint nonce=0;

   function randNum(int _num) private   returns(int) {  //sinartisi gia tixaies times
    int randomnumber = int(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(now, msg.sender, nonce))) % _num;
    if (randomnumber <=0) {
        randomnumber=(-1)*randomnumber;
    }
    nonce++;
    return randomnumber;
    }  

    function attack_hero(uint _heroid, uint _monsterid, int _num  ) external  { 

      hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
      enemy storage monster = enemies[_monsterid];
      int attackofhero=0;
      if(_num==0) { 
       attackofhero=randNum(myhero.attack);
      }
      monster.life=monster.life - attackofhero;

      int attackofmonster=randNum(monster.attack);
      myhero.life=myhero.life - attackofmonster;

      if (monster.life <= 0 && myhero.life >0) { 
        myhero.winCount++;
        myhero.xp+=monster.xp;

        if (randNum(100) > 50 ){ 
              myhero.trophies++;
          }


      }
      if (myhero.xp>=10+2*myhero.lvl){ 
          myhero.lvl++;
          myhero.xp=0; //reset you xp
          myhero.life=basiclife*myhero.lvl;  
          myhero.attack=myhero.attack*myhero.lvl;
        }
      if (myhero.life <= 0 ) { //ita 
          myhero.lossCount++; 

      } 




    }
    function resurrection(uint _heroid) public { 
         hero storage myhero = heroes[_heroid];
         myhero.life=basiclife*myhero.lvl;
     }



}
```

Comment: What is in your genesis file? What version of truffle are you using? What do you do in you migration script? You use the `status` field in the receipt to check if a transaction was successful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to convert code to bytecode.

Comment: How i do that . I am new here